# D3.js : How can I select the first property value from an array of objects?

Tags: d3.js

I have a dataset similar to the below:

```
var data= [ 
            {"home_team": "Juventus", "PlayerID": 1},
            {"home_team": "Juventus", "PlayerID": 2},
            {"home_team": "Juventus", "PlayerID": 3},
            {"home_team": "Juventus", "PlayerID": 4},
            {"home_team": "Juventus", "PlayerID": 5}
        ]
```

I'm trying to extract a single instance of the "home_team" value (as it will always be the same).

If I try to map it using  `.text(function(d,i) {return (d.home_team) })`   it will stack multiple values on top of each other which I don't really want.

I also tried  `.text(function(d,i) {return (d.away_team)[0] })`  but that just returns the first letter of the value each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose d is the data. So you have to select the first member of the array. Try This:

```
.text(function(d,i) {return (d[0].home_team) })
```

Comment: ahhh,  didn't work but got me in the right direction. Using "data" rather than "d" did the job:

.text(function(d,i) {return (data[0].home_team) })